# ckeditor value not saving inside database in c#

Tags: asp.net, editor

i have implemented fck editor in my site it is working properly. but now i want to change it into ck editor. the editor is working but the values are not saving to the databse.

this is my code

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="Content" runat="server" BaseHref="~/ckeditor/" Height="400" />

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Web;

using System.Web.UI;

using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Collections;

using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;


using System.Web.Security;

using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

using Dump.BLL;

using System.IO;




public partial class managenationtheme : System.Web.UI.Page
{


 public static string strThemeName = "State-Default";
public static string srtType = "State";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {    


        lblDynamic.Text = "For Dynamic State add key dynamicobjstate where required";
        strThemeName = "State-Default";
        BindState();
        CheckThemeAvailabilityAndLoadPage(strThemeName);
    }
}


protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  Content.Text = string.Empty;
    chkBoxPublish.Checked = false;
    if (ddlState.SelectedItem.Value != "0")
    {
        strThemeName = "State-" + ddlState.SelectedItem.Text;
        CheckThemeAvailabilityAndLoadPage(strThemeName);
        lblResult.Text = ddlState.SelectedItem.Text + " State Theme :" + btnSave.CommandName.ToUpperInvariant() + " Option"; 
    }
    else
    {
        strThemeName = "State-Default";
        CheckThemeAvailabilityAndLoadPage(strThemeName);
        lblResult.Text = "Default State Theme :" + btnSave.CommandName.ToUpperInvariant() + " Option"; 
    }
}

public void CheckThemeAvailabilityAndLoadPage(string ThemeNamestr)
{

    DataSet ds = Dump.BLL.Theme.CheckThemeAvailable(ThemeNamestr);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            btnSave.Text = "Save";
            btnSave.CommandName = "edit";
        Content.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Theme"].ToString();
            chkBoxPublish.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ThemePublished"].ToString());
            if (ddlState.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
            {
                lblResult.Text = "Default State Theme!";
            }
            else
            {
                lblResult.Text = ddlState.SelectedItem.Value.ToString().ToUpperInvariant() + " State Theme!";

            }
        }
        else
        {
            btnSave.Text = "Save";
            btnSave.CommandName = "save";
            chkBoxPublish.Checked = false;
            if (ddlState.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
            {
                lblResult.Text = "Add Default State Theme!";
              Content.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        BindDataList();
}
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnSave.CommandName == "save")
    {
        SaveTheme(strThemeName);
    }
    else if (btnSave.CommandName == "edit")
    {
        EditTheme(strThemeName); 
    }
}

public void EditTheme(string strLocationName)
{
    Theme objtheme = new Theme();
    objtheme.ThemeName = strLocationName; 
    objtheme.ThemeValue =  Content.Text;
    objtheme.ThemePublished = true;
    int i = Dump.BLL.Theme.Update(objtheme);
    if (i > 0)
    {
        lblResult.Text = "Theme Updated and Published!";
        chkBoxPublish.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lblResult.Text = "Error!";
    }
    BindDataList();
}

public void SaveTheme(string strLocationName)
{
    Theme objtheme = new Theme();
    objtheme.ThemeType = srtType;
    objtheme.ThemeName = strLocationName;
    objtheme.ThemeValue =  Content.Text;
    objtheme.ThemePublished = true;
    objtheme.Zip = "";
    objtheme.City = "";
    if (ddlState.SelectedItem.Value != "0")
    {
        objtheme.State = ddlState.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        objtheme.State = "All-State-Default";
    }
    int i = Dump.BLL.Theme.Insert(objtheme);
    if (i > 0)
    {
        lblResult.Text = "Theme Created and Published!";
        btnSave.CommandName = "edit";
        chkBoxPublish.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lblResult.Text = "Error!";
    }
    BindDataList();
}

protected void chkBoxPublish_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Theme objtheme = new Theme();
     objtheme.ThemeName = strThemeName;
     objtheme.ThemePublished = chkBoxPublish.Checked;
     int i = Dump.BLL.Theme.CheckPublishStatus(objtheme);
     if (i > 0)
     {
         if (chkBoxPublish.Checked)
         {
             lblResult.Text = "Theme Published!";
         }
         else
         {
             lblResult.Text = "Theme Un-Published!";
         }

     }
     BindDataList();
}

public void BindDataList()
{
    DataSet ds = Dump.BLL.Theme.GetDefaultThemeStateList();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataListDefaultState.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        DataListDefaultState.DataBind();
        lblDataListDefaultState.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        lblDataListDefaultState.Text = "Sorry! No Items added";
    }

    DataSet ds2 = Dump.BLL.Theme.GetUniqueThemeStateList();
    if (ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataListUniqueState.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];
        DataListUniqueState.DataBind();
        lblDataListUniqueState.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        lblDataListUniqueState.Text = "Sorry! No Items added";
    }

}

}
```

i have changed only one change  ie, i change Fckeditor1.value to Content.text.

where Content is my ckeditor id.

can anyone help please?